# Visual Studio lag on switching between designer and xaml

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Since a while I noticed an odd and very annoying lag when switching between the xaml view and the designer space in Silverlight apps (ie. changing the keyboard focus by clicking into the respective other space). The duration varies but sometimes Visual Studio freezes for seconds on every such switch, which is frustrating.

Interestingly, this is only happening as long as the file in question has unsaved changes.

I have some extensions installed, for example the DevExpress toolkit and an older .NET Reflector.

I'm not entirely sure when it first happened, but I believe I didn't always had this after I switched to Visual Studio 2012 - certainly not before with 2010.

Anyone got a clue what might be triggering this and how to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it sounds a bit off, but I found the culprit to be RIA Services.

Switching between the designer and the xaml view is never instantaneous, but the presence of the auto-generated RIA Services code makes it slower from slightly more annoying to outright offensive, depending on how complex the project is.

Luckily this is easily fixed by having the auto-generated RIA Services code live in its own client library, which is considered best practice anyway.

I wonder what's going on behind the scenes that causes RIA Services to have that kind of influence on the development environment.